# Spring Initializr not able to load in Google Chrome But its Open in Microsoft Edge

Tags: spring, google-chrome, spring-initializr

Spring Initializr not able to load in Google Chrome But its Open in Microsoft Edge

**In Google Chrome :**

[image: enter code here]

**In Microsoft Edge :**

[image]

Can you suggest me why **spring initializr** not opening in google chrome.

Comment: spring initializr is able to load in google Chrome now

Answer (score 1):

To avoid this, delete your all cache data, all cookies and other site data.
Go to your chrome history and clear:

1. Cookies and other site data
2. Cached images and files.

Now load the Spring initializr again.

It worked for me.